# Can I create an Outlook 2010 add in in Visual Studio Professional 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, outlook-2010

I have just installed Visual Studio Professional 2013 and wish to write an add in for Outlook 2010, however there is only an option to start a new project for an Outlook 2013 add in. When I search for more templates under the web option I can not find what I want. Is there a way to create an Outlook 2010 add in without installing a different version of Visual Studio? Or will a 2013 add in work in 2010?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the New Project dialog, **first** change the .NET Framework target version to 4.0.  Combobox at the top of the dialog.  You'll then see the Office 2010 project templates as well.